# Abstract type in constructor instead of Concrete type

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have an object that suppose to be data which is returned to client side after
they calls web method.

```
        // NewData1.cs
        public NewData1(Concrete1 con)
        {
            ID = con.ID;
            var results= con.listOfResults();

                var something= con.GetSomething();
                Something = new List<Somethings>();

                con.DoSomething();
            }

            // NewData2.cs
            public NewData2(Concrete2 con)
            {
                ID = con.ID;
                var results= con.listOfResults();

                var something= con.GetSomething();
                Something = new List<Somethings>();

                con.DoSomething();
            }

            // NewData3.cs
            public NewData3(Concrete3 con)
            {
                ID = con.ID;
                var results= con.listOfResults();

                var something= con.GetSomething();
                Something = new List<Somethings>();

                con.DoSomething();
            }
```

As you can see those classes do the same thing (it not my code..i want to change it).
The only different thing is the Concrete types (1,2,3) that do different logic when calling their methods.

Do you know a way to reduce those classes to one class but still make each of them to their special logic and not the same?

Comment: Not with arguments of different types, unless they too inherit a common base class, or you can somehow get it to work with a generic method (which often also requires a common base class or delegates to translate).

Answer (score 1):

If your `Concrete1`, `Concrete2` and `Concrete3` classes share same methods, you can extract this into an **interface** and make them implement it:

```
// an interface is simply a contract
interface ICanGetSomething
{
    int ID { get; }
    List<Result> ListOfResults();
    Something GetSomething();
}

// your concrete classes should all implement the same interface
class Concrete1 : ICanGetSomething { ... }
class Concrete2 : ICanGetSomething { ... }
class Concrete3 : ICanGetSomething { ... }
```

This way you only need a single method to handle all of them:

```
public void NewData(ICanGetSomething con)
{
    ID = con.ID;
    var results = con.ListOfResults();
    var something = con.GetSomething();
    ...
}
```

If they also share the same functionality, you can also use a common abstract class to reuse all common code:

```
abstract class Base : ICanGetSomething { ... }

// your concrete classes should all inherit from the same base class
class Concrete1 : Base { ... }
class Concrete2 : Base { ... }
class Concrete3 : Base { ... }
```

Either way, I recommend using **interfaces** for defining contracts. Since C# does not support multiple inheritance, you don't want to force all concrete implementations to derive from a single base class (unless it's necessary). This still means that you will use inheritance where there is shared functionality, but your `NewData` method should accept the interface for the parameter, not the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You want an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // Use protected fields to store data that only this class and derived
    // classes can access.
    protected List<Something> storedSomethings;

    //Define an abstract method signature for methods that the concrete classes
    // have very different implementations for:
    public abstract List<Something>GetSomethings();

    //Use a virtual method for methods that are identical or similar on 
    //the concrete classes:
    public virtual void AddSomethings(List<Something> addList)
    {
        storedSomethings.Add(addList);
    }
}
```

Then your concrete classes are implemented like so:

```
public class Concrete1 : BaseClass
{

    public override List<Something> GetSomethings()
    {
    //actual logic here
    }

    //override any other abstract methods
}

public class Concrete2 : BaseClass
{

    public override List<Something> GetSomethings()
    {
    //actual logic here
    }

    //override any other abstract methods
}
```

Concrete3 is slightly different, it needs to filter on addsomethings:

```
public class Concrete3 : BaseClass
{

    public override List<Something> GetSomethings()
    {
    //actual logic here
    }

    //override any other abstract methods

    //For some reason this class doesn't want all somethings, so it overrides
    // the base method and filters before calling the base method
    public override AddSomethings(List<Something> addList)
    {
        base.AddSomethings(addList.Where(s => s.Condition == false));
    }
}
```

Now, you should only need one newdata class:

```
public newdata(BaseClass classInstance)
{
    //As long as every method you want to call is defined on BaseClass
    // and implemented on the concrete classes, you can just do:
    classInstance.GetSomething();
}
```

Comment: Peter, if you call baseClass.GetSomthing how will it know what GetSomething to call? Concrete1?Concrete2?Conrete3?

Comment: It will call the method on the object that you have.  So if you passed in a Concrete2 to newdata, it would perform all the actions on the concrete2 instance that was passed in.

Comment: He may be confused because of this line `BaseClass.GetSomething();`. That implies a static method for the class. Maybe you should change your example to reflect the fact you mean call GetSomething() on an instance of the class

Comment: @Kazuo: yes, fixing the last snippet to make it actually compile would be a good idea.

Comment: @DevTraveler: Google for "vtable" or "dynamic dispatch". [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) has a pretty good explanation on how virtual methods (usually) work under the hood.

Comment: @DevTraveler I made some edits for clarity, and also added an example of a virtual method, which is potentially very useful in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following base class.

```
public class Concrete
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual something GetSomething()
    {

    }

    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

Have your concrete1, concrete2 etc classes extend Concrete. Those classes will be able to override the GetSomething method if they need to.
Then you just need one of these.

```
public NewData2(Concrete con)
{
    ID = con.ID;
    var results= con.listOfResults();

    var something= con.GetSomething();
    Something = new List<Somethings>();

    con.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: A couple of remarks: first, a base class is usually named `Base` or something. `Concrete` implies it's a "useful" implementation of an abstraction. And the base class doesn't have to be `abstract` if it contains no abstract methods.

Comment: True. Tbh I prefer your answer of using interfaces which I had thought of after blasting out my answer. But it's done now and no point changing it to match an already existing answer. Ill edit mine and leave it here in case someone can get any use from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract base class from Concrete if all 3 deriving classes have the exact same signatures.

The base class :

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseClass
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public abstract List<string> ListOfResults();
    public abstract string GetSomething();
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

Your concrete derive from it :

```
public class Concrete1 : AbstractBaseClass
{
    public override List<string> ListOfResults()
    {
        // Logic
    }

    public override string GetSomething()
    {
        // Logic
    }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        // Logic
    }
}
```

Set the argument as the base class :

```
public void NewData(AbstractBaseClass abs)
{
    ID = abs.ID;

    var results= abs.listOfResults();
    var something= abs.GetSomething();
    abs.DoSomething();
}
```

You can now do, for example :

```
NewData data = new NewData(new Concrete1());
```

All calls in NewData constructor will be directed to the Concrete1 child class.

If you can have only one instance of NewData, you can use the [Stategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to change the concrete class when needed.